# Remove kml layer dynamically on jquery map plugin

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map in my App maniputated with jquery map plugin, I have put kml layer with:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('loadKML', 'kmlFile', 'http://www.mydomain.com/kmlfiles.kml');
```

I need set visible and not visible with an checkbox controls, there is any way to set visible false to kml layer with jquery map plugin?

Best

For reference of jquery map plugin click [here](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code#Example_KML/GeoRSS)

This is my code

```
if(m.checked){              
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('loadKML', 'railAccess', 'http://www.mydomain.org/propertiesch/js/kmlFile.kml');
            }else{
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','overlays>kmlFile').setMap(null);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Welcome to another bad documented maps-library.**

The overlays are stored in the overlays-property:

It has to be:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('get','overlays>kmlFile').setMap(null);
```

Comment: Thank you Molle, This solution work fine but only the first time, If I click on checkbox to load kml file two times the second time no clear the overlay kml

Comment: I has been include the code on question, the first time work fine, but the second time only shot kml again, but not remove on next click

Comment: It's forced by a disadvantageous implementation of `loadKML`. When you set the map to null it will not remove the railAccess-property. When you call loadKML again with the same uniqueIdentifier(railAccess) and the property already exists, it returns this property .  But while it retrieves the property, it creates a  new KMLLayer-instance(what shouldn't happen), which is not accessible in any manner.

Comment: **A possible solution:** delete the property after you set the map to null:  `delete $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','overlays').railAccess;`  **A better solution:** check if `railAccess` already exists, and when it does only set the `map`-option of the KMLLayer.

Comment: Great solution, thanks you Dr.Molle I has set $('#map_canvas').gmap('get','overlays').railAccess to null and work fine.